# JSF Image and absolute path

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, absolute-path

I know that for JSF to display an image, the path have to be from the web/application server root, not the system root. So no absolute path. But here is my problem. Since I will allow the user to upload their own pictures and later display them, I need to save the images somewhere. However, if I save the image inside my project, the future project redeploy might erase my pictures. As a result I think, it is best to upload to a folder that is not effected by future redeploy. But then h:graphicImage or p:graphicImage would not allow me to use absolute path. What are my options to solve this problem?

I know this give me the path to my project-war

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();  
String path = servletContext.getRealPath("");
```

**Is there a way to get me to the web/application root?**

Primefaces 2.2-RC2
Glassfish 3.0.1
Mojarra 2.0.3
Java EE 6

**EDIT**

**After a bit research, I learn the PrimeFaces allow you to stream the content of the image using `FileInputStream`, and you can `FileInputStream` using absolute path. This can be a good solution, until, I tested and find out that this can only work on RequestScoped and SessionScoped Bean, but not ViewScoped.**

Here is the link I post to notify their developers about this major bugs. 
http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7052

Any other idea?

Comment: The above link contain a solution for me. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Just image a special servlet, `ImageServlet` that is mapped to `/image/*` (for example), and send the images from it (getting them as an `InputStream`, and writing this to the response `OutputStream`)

Comment: will you please give me a bit of sample code?

Comment: @Harry: check the duplicate link for that :)

Comment: @BalusC: I am reading it now. I also have couple questions for you as well? Thank you